# Using map for Promise.all returns array of undefined when returning promises nested in a then block

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, ecmascript-6, promise

I have a question. I am currently learning how to use promises but I have run into a problem that I haven't found the answer for after extensive searching. I am trying using map to get an array of promises that are the result of a then block to process in a Promise.all, yet the following does not work, what is going wrong here?

```
let promises = myArray.map(result => 
    {
        searchPromise(result.type).then((searchReply) => 
        {
            return processReply(result, searchReply)
        });
    }
);

Promise.all(promises).then(c => console.log(c)); //array of Undefined, but 
                                                 //want to get results from
                                                 //processReply function
```

Comment: Agreed there are some syntax errors, but you're probably getting an array of undefined because `myArray.map(...);` is not returning anything (implicit return of `undefined`).

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Fixed, thank you.

Comment: @user87002 You're missing a return statement. Should be `return searchPromise(...` Alternatively you could remove the curly braces on your arrow function body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `map` function is not returning anything, only your `then` function:

```
let promises = myArray.map(result => 
    {
        return searchPromise(result.type).then((searchReply) => 
        {
            return processReply(result, searchReply)
        });
    }
);
```

Alternatively, omit the curly braces as stated in the comments, to force a return:

```
let promises = myArray.map(result => 
    searchPromise(result.type).then((searchReply) =>  processReply(result, searchReply)
 ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're likely getting an array filled with `undefined` because your call to `myArray.map` was not returning anything, thus implicitly returning `undefined`. Assuming `searchPromise` and `processReply` both return a `Promise`, this should work:

```
let promises = myArray.map(result => {
  return searchPromise(result.type).then((searchReply) => {
    return processReply(result, searchReply)
  });
});

Promise.all(promises).then(c => console.log(c));
```